# mat-slide-toggle shouldn't change it's state when I click cancel in confirmation window

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

When I checked the slide toggle it should work as expected. But when I try to uncheck it there is a confirmation window asking if you are sure. When I click cancel in that confirmation window, still the toggle changes to unchecked, which shouldn't happen. It should stay in the same state.

Here is my Html and TS Code

```
// html
<mat-slide-toggle 
   (change)="change($event)" [checked]="isChecked()" >
     To-pay
   </mat-slide-toggle>
```

TS code:

```
// ts
    change(e) {
       if(this.checked) {
           if(confirm("Are you sure")) {
              console.log("toggle")
           }
           else {
              e.stopPropagation();
                console.log("toggle should not change if I click the cancel button")
           }
        }
    }
```

when the confirmation window comes while trying to uncheck the toggle button and I click the cancel option there, nothing should happen to the toggle. stopPropagation() is also not working.

**Edit1** :I tried doing return false in else statement. didn't worked. Even tried to change the e.checked = false. It just changed the event object value but didn't prevent the toggle from slidding

Comment: What about a "return false" instead of the stopPropagation ?

Comment: I tried it. didn't worked

Comment: Is "this.checked" true when you pass in this method at uncheck ? Maybe the problem is you have to "else" on the first if and not the second one...

Comment: ya this.checked is true when i try to uncheck. if this.checked is false , it shouldn't enter the code of showing confirm window

Comment: What version of Angular do you use ?

Comment: I am using angular 5

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use `stopPropagation` with `mat-slide-toggle`, you will need to programmatically set the checked value back to `true` on the event in your else condition.

```
else {
    e.source.checked = true;
    console.log("toggle should not change if I click the cancel button")
}
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79yf7m?embed=1&file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Comment: it Worked. Thanks. "source" was what missing in my trials.

Comment: Sometimes I cant understand why they hide this stuff when it is so clear we should use such behavior....

Comment: it is Perfect!!

Comment: Hey, I have similar situation with a difference where I do not have the access to event object. How can I implement the same behavior?

Comment: You will need to bind to the event in your markup so that you can gain access to the event via your event handler.

Answer (score 5):

I was using `MatDialog` as the confirmation window and I noticed the following behavior:
when `MatDialog` is opened, the mat-slide-toggle displays as `false` / `unchecked` value, even if the user has not made a decision:

[image]

**Demo**: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79yf7m-4gdxbu?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.ts

That's because the `change` event fires **after** the `mat-slide-toggle` value changes.

In order to fix this issue, we have to reset the value to its previous (`true`) immediately after the `change` event fires, then let the user decide, and if it confirms the action, we'll update the value accordingly.

The code would be:

```ts
change(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    // at first, reset to the previous value
    // so that the user could not see that the mat-slide-toggle has really changed
    e.source.checked = true;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
       this.checked = !this.checked;
      }
    })
  } else {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79yf7m-yzwwc7?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the toggle mechanism by listening for click event and then event.preventDefault() / event.stopImmediatePropagation(). Then open your dialog and according to the user selection you toggle the toggle yourself or not: toggleReference.toggle().

No need to set it back to true.

Comment: listening for `click` event is not enough because `mat-slide-toggle` can be toggled also by drag gestures.

Comment: Don't forget about keyboard events -- tab to a slide-toggle and press space or enter, and it will change without firing `click`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the matter is the (change)="eventHandler()" will fire AFTER the value change, while the (ngModelChange)="eventHandler()" will fire BEFORE the value change